# How to download identical torrents through libtorrent?

Tags: python, libtorrent

I use python [bindings](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/python_binding.html) to libtorrent. All works fine.

But there is one problem: 2+ identical torrents download.
They are added at different times and downloaded in different folders.
But for different instances `torrent_handle` I receive the same instance `torrent_info`:

`print handle, handle.get_torrent_info() ...`

> <libtorrent.torrent_handle object at 0x80425f6e0> <libtorrent.torrent_info object at 0x802289fa0>
>   <libtorrent.torrent_handle object at 0x80425f758> <libtorrent.torrent_info object at 0x802289fa0>
>   <libtorrent.torrent_handle object at 0x80425f7d0> <libtorrent.torrent_info object at 0x802289fa0>

How can I correct in libtorrent download multiple identical torrents?

Is not a standard case but a rare situation.

Comment: Since it's the Exact same torrent, donwload it to one folder, and then copy it over to the target folder when ready. Downloading the same info twice is pointless.

Comment: These torrents are downloaded with different files priorities (downloaded only part of the torrent, `prioritize_files` method).

From the first instance may be needed first 20 files. From the second - the first and the last two. And so on. Priority setting by the user.

Comment: Downloading only certain files into different directories might make sense, but different priorities does not. It is still the same data, downloading the exact same data twice is not sensible.